# Multiple dependant variables in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

What is the simplest way to implement multiple changeable variables that depend on each other?

For example we have a price before discount which cannot change and we can:

1. apply the discount and the price after discount should update,
2. or change the price after discount and the discount should update accordingly.

I have came up with the following solution for this example: https://jsfiddle.net/2wh6cgq5/1/

Can it be done without having to create separate handlers for each `@input` event and applying the `v-model` directive?

Comment: You can try to use computed props with a getter and a setter and use them only for v-model and change underlying props only from code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the v-model binding with computed properties so you can control the set logic.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    priceBeforeDiscount: 100,
    discount: 50,
    priceAfterDiscount: 50,
  },
  
  computed: {
    priceAfterDiscountInput: {
      get() {
        return this.priceAfterDiscount;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.priceAfterDiscount = val;
        this.discount = this.priceBeforeDiscount - this.priceAfterDiscount;
      }
    },
    discountInput: {
      get() {
        return this.discount;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.discount = val;
        this.priceAfterDiscount = this.priceBeforeDiscount - this.discount;
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Another possibility is to use watchers on `discount` and `priceAfterDiscount`. It doesn't lead to an infinite loop in this case because the values reach an equilibrium and watchers only run if the value changes. I'd be cautious about using co-dependent watchers in general though.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    priceBeforeDiscount: 100,
    discount: 50,
    priceAfterDiscount: 50,
  },
  
  watch: {
    discount() {
        this.priceAfterDiscount = this.priceBeforeDiscount - this.discount;
    },
    priceAfterDiscount() {
        this.discount = this.priceBeforeDiscount - this.priceAfterDiscount;
    }
  },
})
```

However, I don't really think there's an issue with your solution. If you aren't required to use the v-model directive (e.g. for vee-validate), I'd just convert it to v-bind and do the assignment in the input handler.

Comment: The computed property approach is the most elegant in my opinion. Watchers are risky because if I want to for example round the price and the discount to 2 decimal places it may go into an infinite loop.